In rscopus, how to search by author name and see more than three subject areas
Using rscopus, how can I search by author first and last name, and get back 1) all of the authors' subject areas and 2) the authors' complete affiliation history.
When I use get_complete_author_info(last_name = "Smith", first_name = "John"), it gives me many authors, but returns only up to three subject areas per author. And it only returns current affiliation.
I can then take the author ids (au_id) from the above step and put them into multi_author_info to get the subject areas and affiliation history.
But is there a function that allows me to do everything at once?
